# Подскажите как решить задачу Python

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал методом  a[x][y], ничего не получается, выдает ошибку. Какие функции здесь применимы?

Задача: Дано нечетное число n. Создайте двумерный массив из n×n элементов, заполнив его символами "." (каждый элемент массива является строкой из одного символа). Затем заполните символами "*" среднюю строку массива, средний столбец массива, главную диагональ и побочную диагональ. В результате единицы в массиве должны образовывать изображение звездочки. Выведите полученный массив на экран, разделяя элементы массива пробелами.

как сделать "квадрат" из символов "."? Как квадрат присвоить массиву а.

Output в прикрепленном изображении.

Comment: покажите код как именно вы пробовали, поскольку задача в 4 действия и 1 цикл

Comment: Вопрос о квадрате это уже совсем другой вопрос. Но тоже ничего сложного. просто заполняете все элементы с индексами: `(i, 0), (i, n), (0, j), (n, j)`

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто.

- Первая диагональ - когда `i == j`
- Вторая диагональ - когда `i == n - j - 1` (т.е. `0, 4(5 - 0 - 1)`, `1,3` и т.д.)
- Горизонталь - когда `i == n / 2`, (т.е. `5 // 2 = 2`)
- Вертикаль - когда `j == n / 2`, (т.е. заполняем только индексы, для всех `i`, где `j == n // 2`)

```
n = 5
a = [['*' if i == j or i == n // 2 or j == n // 2 or i == n - j - 1 else '.' for j in range(n) ] for i in range(n)]
```

```
*  .  *  .  *  
.  *  *  *  .  
*  *  *  *  *  
.  *  *  *  .  
*  .  *  .  *
```

P.S. Сразу с выводом:

```
a = [print(' '.join(['*' if i == j or i == n // 2 or j == n // 2 or i == n - j - 1 else '.' for j in range(n)])) for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: а как сделать "квадрат" из символов "."? Можно ли его присвоить массиву а.

Comment: @Сергей, ну можно. Странный немного вопрос :)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без if, заполняем `*` от краев к центру(не тривиальный способ с линиями):

```py
n = 11
b = [['.' for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
nn = n // 2

# fill 4 points
def fill4p(x, y):
    for k in range(4):
        b[x][y] = '*'
        x, y = n - y - 1, x

for i in range(nn + 1):
    fill4p(i, i)
    fill4p(i, nn)
```